# CSS text in center of background image

Tags: html, css

how can I center text on following (Sorry I'm new to CSS):

[image]

**CSS:**

```
suggestion_active { 
    background-image: url(../images/suggestion_active.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:inherit;
    float:inherit;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 36px;
}

suggestion_active_text {
    possition: absolute;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:0px;
}
```

**html:**

```
 <suggestion_active><suggestion_active_text>1</suggestion_active_text></suggestion_active>
```

Also it would be nice if you tell me the best practices of how to do this :)

Comment: Harmen's answer works, but are you making up your own html tags?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set `text-align: center;` to center the text horizontally, and set `line-height: [heightofbox];` to center the text vertically.

Here is a simple [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JKzeG/) of that

---

Note that, if you are working with invalid HTML elements, you need to set them as block elements. So, this should do the trick:

```
customEl {
  display: block;
  ...
}
```

Comment: @harmeen , i was slow in typing and formating...:) my answer should also work right.

Comment: Doesn't align it horizontally (At least not in FF 3.6) - He already has a `text-align: center;` in there...

Comment: @intially i didn't do format on my div code , so it came as 1 in the output , so i have to edit that agian.

Comment: Depends on if those are by default block or inline elements of course. Since those in the OP's example aren't standard HTML elements, it's shooting in the dark.

Comment: @J V , height he should specify the height of image ,

Answer (score 4):

Bit more modern answer maybe?

1. Create a div
2. Place text inside the div

Then using flexbox style div as follows:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
```

ALTERNATIVELY for more dynamic positioning

set your background image div to

```
  positiion: relative;
```

AND your text box div to include

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

- This allows you to move text for instance 20% from the top instead of
  50%.
- translate(-50%,-50%) realigns the anchor of the text div to be in the center, which will be noticeable if you have longer text.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove suggestion_active_text..

Have one div with background image. inside that div do like this

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 1 </div>
```

give background image for above thats it

Comment: @Lukas , text-align center works on text,  now you can give bacground image for this one div...so no need of having two.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to both of your tags and it should do the trick:

```
display: block;
width:100px;
```

Comment: Um... I'm actually testing this here, as in, real html file. So far combined with OPs code it's the only one that works... So yeah, really...

Comment: Still, not really. `vertical-align` just won't work in all browsers. As this is about text only, setting `line-height` is much more elegant.

Comment: I'm talking about the horizontal here, without block and width it won't center horizontally. I didn't even think about vertical at the time, but yes, line-height should be used. Actually, he could make the entire thing in a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I think Flex works better, you can make it aligned to center in both directions.

```
suggestion_active { 
    background-image:url(https://placeimg.com/120/120/tech/sepia);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 36px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; //horizontal alignment
    align-items: center; //vertical alignment
}

suggestion_active_text {
    possition: absolute;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-align: center;
    color:#000;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
suggestion_active_text {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make it more helpful, could you please include some explanation in it because these answers are normally more helpful than code-only answers?